# how do you make the escape key a "killswitch" in python 3.3.2?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, autohotkey

Im using python 3.3.2 in autoflight and I need to code the escape key as an emergency key to abort the script in case the quadcopter is going to hit an object/person.
Here is what the script is at the moment. I just need to know what i need to do to code the escape key as an emergency kill switch.

```
import time
import numpy
import numpy as np
Esc.abort
util.startRecording
control.takeOff()
time.sleep(6)
control.move_distance(0,-0.5,0,0,0.5)
control.move_distance(0,0.2,0,0,0.2)
control.hover()
control.land()
```

Comment: this code is incomplete.  `numpy` is imported twice and never used, `Esc` is undefined, `util` is undefined, and `control` is undefined.

Comment: How much time do we have to answer before the quadcopter hits the object/person??

Comment: Are you sure that aborting the control script is the correct course of action here? If you have an airborne craft that is on a collision course with another object, I would say the thing you do *not* want to do is abort the control script which would leave you with no way to control the craft. Which pretty much guarantees that it will collide with something eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey Solution

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#Persistent

Esc::

IfWinExist, ahk_class yourpythonscript 
{
WinKill, ahk_class yourpythonscript
}
return
```

Refer to documentation to find class name of your script:
[WinTitle Ahk_Class](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class)

Answer (score 0):

If running in Windows, use msvcrt:

```
import msvcrt

aborted = False
while not aborted:
    if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode():
        aborted = True
        break
```

Comment: Whether this is correct or not is up to the OP. However, a short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.